# Pythonic String Testing

Tags: python

For my Information Retrieval class I have to make an index of terms from a group of files. Valid terms contain an alphabetical character, so to test I just made a simple function and use an if/then control statement. Thus far I have:

```
ALPHA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def content_test(term):
    for a in ALPHA:
        if a in term:
            return True
    return False

class FileRead():

    def __init__(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        content = f.read()
        self.terms = content.split()

    def clean(self):
        for term in self.terms:
            if content_test(term) is False:
                try:
                    terms.remove(term)
                except:
                    pass
```

Now this all works fine (I think...) however I've been trying to learn more higher level python and I can't help but think that there is a more pythonic way of checking term validity (maybe using map(), or a lambda function?).

Am I correct or am I just overthinking it?

Comment: Small cleanup that you might find handy.  `import string; ALPHA = string.lowercase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by simplifying `content_test()`:

```
def content_test(term):
    return any(c.isalpha() for c in term)
```

In fact, that's simple enough that you don't really need a separate function for it anymore.

What I'd do in this case is write a generator that yields only valid terms from the file. Then just convert that to a list using the `list()` constructor. This way you can read just a line at a time, which will save you a good bit of memory if the files are large.

```
def read_valid_terms(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            for term in line.split():
                if any(c.isalpha() for c in term):
                    yield term

terms = list(read_valid_terms("terms.txt"))
```

Or if you are just going to iterate over the terms anyway, and only once, then just do that directly rather than making a list:

```
for term in read_valid_terms("terms.txt"):
    print term,
print
```

Comment: Instead of using the various quirks of the `print` statement, I'd rather suggest the print function in the last two lines.

Comment: Eh, just a quickie demo, what's inside the `for` loop is immaterial to the example.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, string objects already contain a method that does that for you:

```
>>> "abc".isalpha()
True
>>> "abc22".isalpha()
False
```

Comment: We need `islower` here too =D

Comment: The problem is valid terms can contain non alpha chars (just not exclusively)

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear. So you mean that it just needs to contain a single alphabetic character someplace in the string?

Comment: Yes, exactly (comment length)

Answer (score 1):

While you could use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), a pythonic way would be to use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
import string
def content_test(term):
    return any((c in string.ascii_lowercase) for c in term)
```

If you also want to allow upper-case and locale-dependent characters, you can use [`str.isalpha`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isalpha).

A couple of additional notes:

- `FileRead` should inherit from `object`, to make sure it's a new-style class.
- Instead of writing `if content_test(term) is False:`, you can simply write `if not content_test(term):`.
- `clean` can be written a lot, ahem, cleaner, by using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def clean(self):
    self.terms = filter(content_test, self.terms)
```

- You're not closing the file `f`, and may therefore leak the handle. Use the `with` statement to automatically close it, like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    self.terms = content.split()
```

Comment: I'm selecting kindall's answer as the correct one, but your's still helped a lot, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

# Match any number of non-whitespace characters, with an alpha char in it.
terms = re.findall('\S*[a-zA-Z]\S*', content)
```