# How to test a string in Python?

Tags: python

I am new in python and I have this code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
for (i, item) in enumerate(s):    
    print item

for (i, item) in enumerate(s):
    if item=="a" or item=="e" or item=="i" or item=="o" or item=="u" 
    vol++
    print vol
```

The first for works goods and show each character as should be.
For the second for I have this error :

```
if item=="a" or item=="e" or item=="i" or item=="o" or item=="u"
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I search this post but it not solved [Pythonic String Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316307/pythonic-string-testing)

Comment: You forgot the `:` after the `if` block.

Comment: You could really simplify your code with `in`: `if item in 'aeiouAEIOU':`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you enumerate when you never use the value `i` anyway?

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
for letter in s:    
    print letter
```

The other loop was missing a colon and indentation.

```
vol = 0
for letter in s:
    if letter in 'aeiou': 
       vol += 1
print vol
```

You can also do it like this:

```
print sum(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in s)
```

Comment: The last one might be a bit confusing, since the keyword `in` are used in two different ways.

Comment: I am a PHP developer. I am  starting to study python. It is why it is a basic question. By the way, your code is good. It prints 5 but show a error. %run "C:/Users/Rayn/PYTHON DOCS/6.00.1X/pset0Test.py". any idea?

Comment: %run "C:/Users/Rayn/PYTHON DOCS/6.00.1X/pset0Test.py"

Comment: That's not a python error message. It's a filepath.

Answer (score 2):

You need the colon at the end

```
if item=="a" or item=="e" or item=="i" or item=="o" or item=="u":
```

Here's a more compact solution:

```
if item in ['aeiou']:
```

Comment: Your condition in the `if` statement is wrong. It should be `if item in 'aeiou'`. Otherwise the condition is only true when item is the string `aeiou`.

Answer (score 1):

missing colon:

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(s):
    if item=="a" or item=="e" or item=="i" or item=="o" or item=="u":
        vol+=1
        print vol
```

This should work.

Edited:
I forgot to mention that Python does not have a `++` operator.

Comment: I still have an error  vol++   ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ++ syntax is not used in python. Use +=1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `:` after the `if` statement. You also have to indent the lines with `vol++` and `print vol`.
Furthermore incrementing in python is done by `+=1`, not by `++`.

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(s):
    if item=="a" or item=="e" or item=="i" or item=="o" or item=="u":
        vol+=1
        print vol
```

Comment: That works. But it outputs %run "C:/Users/Rayn/PYTHON DOCS/6.00.1X/pset0Test.py". Any idea what is this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the : on the end of the if. And the next row has to be indented.